# 'Conflicting changes detected. This may happen when trying to insert multiple entities with the same key.' Entity Framework Code-First Migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm getting this message when trying to update-database.

This is my Configuration.cs file with the seeder:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MiracleMachine.data.ApplicationDbContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

        //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
        //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data. E.g.
        //
        //    context.People.AddOrUpdate(
        //      p => p.FullName,
        //      new Person { FullName = "Andrew Peters" },
        //      new Person { FullName = "Brice Lambson" },
        //      new Person { FullName = "Rowan Miller" }
        //    );
        //
        context.Props.AddOrUpdate(
            p => p.PropName,
            new Prop() { PropName = "sharpie" },
            new Prop() { PropName = "coin" },
            new Prop() { PropName = "playing cards" },
            new Prop() { PropName = "coffee mug" },
            new Prop() { PropName = "phone" },
            new Prop() { PropName = "keys" },
            new Prop() { PropName = "sunglasses" },
            new Prop() { PropName = "headphones" },
            new Prop() { PropName = "ring" },
            new Prop() { PropName = "lighter" }
            );
        context.SaveChanges();

        context.Theories.AddOrUpdate(
            t => t.TheoryId,
            new Theory()
            {
                TheoryId = 0,
                TheoryName = "Production",
                TheoryDescription = "Make it appear out of nowhere!"
            },
            new Theory()
            {
                TheoryId = 1,
                TheoryName = "Vanish",
                TheoryDescription = "Make it vanish into thin air!"
            },
            new Theory()
            {
                TheoryId = 2,
                TheoryName = "Transportation",
                TheoryDescription = "Make it vanish, and then reappear somewhere impossible!"
            },
            new Theory()
            {
                TheoryId = 3,
                TheoryName = "Transformation", // This uses TWO props
                TheoryDescription = "Cause one of these items to change into the other item!"
            },
            new Theory()
            {
                TheoryId = 4,
                TheoryName = "Multiplication",
                TheoryDescription = "Magically duplicate this item again and again!"
            },
            new Theory()
            {
                TheoryId = 5,
                TheoryName = "Penetration", // This uses TWO props
                TheoryDescription = "Cause the two items to inexplicably pass through each other"
            },
            new Theory()
            {
                TheoryId = 6,
                TheoryName = "Restoration",
                TheoryDescription = "Destroy the item in some way. Restore it."
            },
            new Theory()
            {
                TheoryId = 7,
                TheoryName = "Levitation",
                TheoryDescription = "Make the item float in mid-air!"
            });
        context.SaveChanges();

        //////////////////////////////////////////// The following seeds user data

        // ApplicationUser table seeder
        UserStore<ApplicationUser> userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);

        RoleStore<Role> roleStore = new RoleStore<Role>(context);
        RoleManager<Role> roleManager = new RoleManager<Role>(roleStore);

        if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Admin"))
            roleManager.Create(new Role { Name = "Admin" });

        if (!roleManager.RoleExists("User"))
            roleManager.Create(new Role { Name = "User" });

        IdentityResult result = null; // Sets the result to null. Used for error checking.

        /////////// Admin (1)
        ApplicationUser admin1 = userManager.FindByName("MagicRawb");

        if (admin1 == null)
        {
            admin1 = new ApplicationUser
            {
                FirstName = "Rob",
                LastName = "Greenlee",
                UserName = "magicrawb",
                Email = "magicrawb@test.com"//,
                //Gender = Gender.Male
            };
        }

        result = userManager.Create(admin1, "asdfasdf");
        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            string error = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault();
            throw new Exception(error);
        }

        userManager.AddToRole(admin1.Id, "Admin"); // Add user1 to Admin role
        admin1 = userManager.FindByName("magicrawb"); // Assign user1 data to variable user1

        /////////// Admin (2)
        ApplicationUser admin2 = userManager.FindByName("admin2");

        if (admin2 == null)
        {
            admin2 = new ApplicationUser
            {
                FirstName = "Bekah",
                LastName = "Sells",
                UserName = "admin2",
                Email = "admin2@test.com"//,
                                         // Gender = Gender.Female
            };
        }

        result = userManager.Create(admin2, "asdfasdf");
        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            string error = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault();
            throw new Exception(error);
        }

        userManager.AddToRole(admin2.Id, "Admin"); // Add user1 to Admin role
        admin1 = userManager.FindByName("admin2"); // Assign user1 data to variable user1

        /////////// User (1)
        ApplicationUser user1 = userManager.FindByName("user1");

        if (user1 == null)
        {
            user1 = new ApplicationUser
            {
                FirstName = "Lance",
                LastName = "Burton",
                UserName = "user1",
                Email = "user1@test.com"//,
                //Gender = Gender.Male
            };
        }

        result = userManager.Create(user1, "asdfasdf");
        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            string error = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault();
            throw new Exception(error);
        }

        userManager.AddToRole(user1.Id, "User"); // Add user1 to Admin role
        user1 = userManager.FindByName("user1"); // Assign user1 data to variable user1

        /////////// User (2)
        ApplicationUser user2 = userManager.FindByName("user2");

        if (user2 == null)
        {
            user2 = new ApplicationUser
            {
                FirstName = "David",
                LastName = "Stone",
                UserName = "user2",
                Email = "user2@test.com"
                //Gender = Gender.Male
            };
        }

        result = userManager.Create(user2, "asdfasdf");
        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            string error = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault();
            throw new Exception(error);
        }

        userManager.AddToRole(user2.Id, "User"); // Add user1 to Admin role
        user2 = userManager.FindByName("user2"); // Assign user1 data to variable user1

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

}

First I was using AddOrUpdate by PropId and TheoryId, but wasn't actually setting the Id's. I thought this might be the problem and changed it. I've tried deleting the migrations and the ApplicationDbContext and redoing it completely (as per another similar question I found on here) and I'm still getting the same error.

**EDIT :** Maybe I should include the DbContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
    public IDbSet<Prop> Props { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<Theory> Theories { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<NewTrick> NewTricks { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: there are many `SaveChanges` in your code, so it would be helpful if you point out where the exception was thrown at.

Comment: Please cut this down to the code that demonstrates the problem. It's not clear where exactly you get the error.

Comment: Could you help me with this? I don't know where the error is happening. I added break points at the SaveChanges and ran it again. It didn't stop at any of the break points and still gave the same general error in the Package Manager Console.

Comment: well I think you can try finding out where it is via the Stack trace, it would be harder but that's the only thing the console window provides for you.

Comment: *First I was using AddOrUpdate by PropId and TheoryId* You're still checking by `TheoryId`.

Comment: Is `TheoryId` an identity column in the database?

Comment: Yes, it is set as the Key.

Comment: Yes, obviously, but does it have an identity specification?